Android Studio Scroll only Text in textview inside RecyclerView but not all page
I have a problem with RecyclerView.
When I fill my descTextView to my adapter file. DescTextView Scrool is not working. I want to scrool just text in descTextView.
If i change  layout_height to match_parent in item_detail_view.xml then all pages starts to scroll. But I dont want it.
Here is my codes. What is wrong
Sometimes scroll is working and lost how is work I dont know.
I tried some codes bu I dont find the problem.



//fragment_home.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

//And This is HomeFragment Codes

package com.example.mybottomapplication.ui.home

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.example.mybottomapplication.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding
import android.widget.Toast
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import android.util.Log
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity




class HomeFragment : Fragment(), CategoryAdapter.OnItemClickListener, ProductAdapter.OnProductClickListener {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private var isShowingProducts = false
    private var isShowingProductDetail = false

    private var categories: List<CategoryData> = emptyList()
    private var products: List<ProductData> = emptyList()
    private var productDetails: List<ProductDetailData> = emptyList()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        // RecyclerView'i bağla ve ayarla
        setupRecyclerView()

        val token = PreferenceHelper.getToken(requireContext())
        if (token != null) {
            loadCategories(token)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Token is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                if (isShowingProductDetail) {
                    showProducts()
                } else if (isShowingProducts) {
                    showCategories()
                } else {
                    isEnabled = false
                    requireActivity().onBackPressed()
                }
            }
        })

        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    private fun setupRecyclerView() {
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2) // Default olarak iki sütunlu GridLayoutManager
        binding.recyclerView.addItemDecoration(GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, 16, true)) // 16dp aralık, kenar dahil
    }

    private fun loadCategories(token: String) {
        RetrofitClient.instance.getCategories(token).enqueue(object : Callback<CategoryResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<CategoryResponse>, response: Response<CategoryResponse>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val categoryResponse = response.body()
                    if (categoryResponse != null && categoryResponse.success) {
                        categories = categoryResponse.data.filter { it.parent_id != "0" }
                        val adapter = CategoryAdapter(requireContext(), categories, this@HomeFragment)
                        binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Katalog" // Set initial header text
                    } else {
                        Log.e("CategoryResponse", "Response is unsuccessful or empty")
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("CategoryResponse", "Failed to load categories: ${response.message()}")
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Failed to load categories", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<CategoryResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("CategoryResponse", "Request failed: ${t.message}")
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Request failed: ${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onItemClicked(categoryId: String, categoryName: String) {
        val token = PreferenceHelper.getToken(requireContext())
        if (token != null) {
            loadProducts(token, categoryId)
            (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = categoryName // Update header text with category name
            isShowingProducts = true
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Token is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    private fun loadProducts(token: String, categoryId: String) {
        RetrofitClient.instance.getProducts(token, categoryId).enqueue(object : Callback<ProductResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ProductResponse>, response: Response<ProductResponse>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val productResponse = response.body()
                    if (productResponse != null && productResponse.success) {
                        products = productResponse.data
                        val adapter = ProductAdapter(requireContext(), products, this@HomeFragment) // Here passing context and listener
                        binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    } else {
                        Log.e("ProductResponse", "Response is unsuccessful or empty")
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("ProductResponse", "Failed to load products: ${response.message()}")
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Failed to load products", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ProductResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("ProductResponse", "Request failed: ${t.message}")
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Request failed: ${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }

    private fun loadProductDetails(token: String, productId: String) {
        RetrofitClient.instance.getProductDetails(token, productId).enqueue(object : Callback<ProductDetailResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ProductDetailResponse>, response: Response<ProductDetailResponse>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val productDetailResponse = response.body()
                    if (productDetailResponse != null && productDetailResponse.success) {
                        productDetails = productDetailResponse.data
                        val adapter = ProductDetailAdapter(requireContext(), productDetails)
                        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 1) // Tek sütunlu GridLayoutManager
                        binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()




                    } else {
                        Log.e("ProductDetailResponse", "Response is unsuccessful or empty")
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("ProductDetailResponse", "Failed to load product details: ${response.message()}")
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Failed to load product details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ProductDetailResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("ProductDetailResponse", "Request failed: ${t.message}")
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Request failed: ${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onProductClicked(productId: String, productName: String) {
        val token = PreferenceHelper.getToken(requireContext())
        if (token != null) {
            loadProductDetails(token, productId)
            (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = productName // Update header text with product name
            isShowingProductDetail = true
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Token is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }



    fun isShowingProducts(): Boolean {
        return isShowingProducts
    }

    fun isShowingProductDetail(): Boolean {
        return isShowingProductDetail
    }

    fun showCategories() {
        val adapter = CategoryAdapter(requireContext(), categories, this)
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2) // İki sütunlu GridLayoutManager
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Katalog" // Reset header text
        isShowingProducts = false
        isShowingProductDetail = false
    }

    fun showProducts() {
        val adapter = ProductAdapter(requireContext(), products, this)
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2) // İki sütunlu GridLayoutManager
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Ürünler" // Reset header text
        isShowingProducts = true
        isShowingProductDetail = false
    }
}

//And Adapter Codes are here 

package com.example.mybottomapplication.ui.home

import android.content.Context
import android.text.Html
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.mybottomapplication.R
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod


class ProductDetailAdapter(private val context: Context, private val products: List<ProductDetailData>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductDetailAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_product_detail, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val product = products[position]
        holder.nameTextView.text = product.ProductName
        holder.productId = product.ProductId
        holder.descTextView.text = Html.fromHtml(product.Details, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
        holder.descTextView.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod()




        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
            .load("https://domain/${product.ImageUrls[0].Small}")
            .into(holder.imageView)




        // Sekmelerin tıklama olayları
        holder.tab1.setOnClickListener {
            holder.descTextView.text = Html.fromHtml(product.Details, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
        }

        holder.tab2.setOnClickListener {
            holder.descTextView.text = Html.fromHtml(product.Additional5, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY) // Tab2 için Additional5 verisi
        }

        holder.tab3.setOnClickListener {
            holder.descTextView.text = Html.fromHtml(product.Additional1, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY) // Tab3 için Additional1 verisi
        }

    }



    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return products.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val nameTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView)
        val descTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descTextView)
        val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        val tab1: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tab1)
        val tab2: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tab2)
        val tab3: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tab3)
        var productId: String? = null
    }
}


//And item_activity_detail.xml

androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/category_item_background">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/nameTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_background_selector"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_background_selector"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_background_selector"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabLayout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



I tried nestedScrollview and using to textview scrolls I cant work healty
